# how to draw the graph in R?

Tags: r

I can get photo11 with the following code,how can  i fix my code to change photo1 into photo2?

```
x = seq(0.5, 0.9, length = 200)
y = dnorm(x,0.7,0.0458)
plot(x, y,type="l",xlab="my_x_lab")
```

this is a photo1.jpg
   [image]

this is a photo2.jpg
    [image]

and ,how to fix my code to change photo2.jpg into photo3.jpg?there are
only two scales(0.7,0.8) in the x_lab.
this is a photo3.jpg
 [image]

to fix the code to get rid of `y`  in the y_lab to change photo3.jpg into photo4.jpg?
this is a photo4.jpg.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your original question rather than posting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it. `xaxt='n', ann=FALSE` removes the x-axis and annotations. `axis(...)` puts the x-axis only at the specified points. `mtext()` will put marginal text on the bottom axis.

```
x <- seq(0.5, 0.9, length = 200)
y <- dnorm(x,0.7,0.0458)
plot(x, y, type="l", xaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
axis(1, at=c(0.7, 0.8))
mtext("my_x_lab", 1, at=0.9, line=2)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Suppress the x axis and add blanks for the labels where you do not want them.

```
plot(x, y, type="l",  yaxt="n",ann=FALSE,bty="n", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9), labels=c("", "", 0.7, 0.8, 0.9) )
mtext("Proportions", 1, at=0.9, line=2)
```

[image]

If you insist on omitting the ticks in the left hand side its going to be more difficult because the base line will only extend from the first tick.

Except this answer is better than mine.

[how to draw the graph in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713951/how-to-draw-the-graph-in-r)

I guess it means this is homework? Oh NOOOO, it's the same poster...  you are posting duplicate questions? Bad poster , bad poster. Shame on you.